# ggVennDiagram: values inside circles by changing data do not change

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is part of my data:

```r
dd<-read.table (text=" Out1 Out2
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes Yes
Yes Yes
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes NO
Yes Yes
Yes Yes
Yes Yes

", header=TRUE)
```

I would like to get a Veen diagram for this data using ggVennDiagram.
I use the following codes to get the diagram.

```
ggVennDiagram(dd[1:2], label_alpha = 0) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high = "green")
```

This gives me the Venn diagram, but when I change the "Yes"s or "NO"s, the numbers do not change inside the circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your input data is in the wrong format. Are you perhaps looking for this?

```r
my_list <- list(Out1 = which(dd$Out1 == "Yes"), 
                Out2 = which(dd$Out2 == "Yes")) 

ggVennDiagram(my_list, label_alpha = 0) + 
  ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think it should be based on Out1 and Out2

Comment: @user330 see my update - is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you, not sure why we change Yess or Nos, the sum is not equal to 29?

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. In your sample data there are 24 instances where only out1 is Yes, and 5 instances where both out1 and out2 are yes. There are no instances where only out2 is yes. This is what the diagram shows. Can you tell me what output you are expecting please?

Comment: The output is not the issue. The issue is that when you change the data the total sample should not change. I see the codes produce different samples. So this does not help sorry.

Comment: @user330 the original data doesn't change - it is simply used to create a structure that is in the format that ggVennDiagram accepts. If you want a Venn diagram created with this function you need to format your data in a way that it accepts. I don't really understand what you mean that the total sample should not change. Your original dataset can be fully reconstructed from the `my_list` object. Perhaps you can edit your question to point out why my answer isn't helpful and what exactly you are looking for so that someone is able to help you?